# Jenkins builds all starting late

Tags: jenkins

We've inherited a set of Jenkins builds. They all seem to start 90-100 seconds after the desired time. For example, a build with a schedule of */5 * * * * starts at :01:37, :06.29, :11:43, etc., instead of :00, :05, :10, etc. that I would expect.

There are a few builds set to run at /5, but they are all delayed and anyway only last a few seconds each.

I see a global 'quiet period' setting of 5.

The system as a whole does not seem busy. There are usually idle executors, and often nothing at all is building.

For most of the builds this isn't a concern, but there are a couple that we would like to make as precise as possible.

Is my expectation wrong? Is there a config option I'm missing? I should add that I am new to Jenkins and may be missing something obvious.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We updated Jenkins from 1.492 to 1.565 and the problem went away. Jobs now start within a few seconds of the expected time.

Answer (score 0):

We did not find the cause of Jenkins jobs starting late. We hacked up a workaround by having Jenkins start a script on the remote server that sleeps until the desired time. This creates a new problem by tying up a Jenkins executor for several minutes, so we have the remote script spawn a wait task and then return to Jenkins immediately. This creates another problem in that the output of the remote script is lost because when it completes it has no connection to Jenkins anymore. We get around that by having the remote script write its results into a tmp file, and returning the results of the previous run.

So we have a seriously hacked-up solution that actually works fine for our purposes.